# Bluemix - getting 403, error code: 10003 when using cf create-quota

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I have a pay-as-you-go account. Recently tried to set the qIBM quota on one of the organizations I have created and received a "Not authorized.." message. I have assigned myself all the roles but still getting the issue. Tried the **cf create-quota** and got the same error. Any pointers ? or do I need to involve IBM support?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of cf commands that are not allowed to standard users but are reserved to administrators (e.g. create-org, delete-org, set-quota, create-quota, delete-quota and update-quota). Trying to execute those commands the error is indeed 10003. Please contact Bluemix Support to require the action you need.

Answer (score 0):

There is a reserved set of commands that only administrators can run.  These commands include things around quota and creating orgs.  If you need an org created please email id@bluemix.net.